# How do I Call a URL Action from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Attachments", "Transactions")';
url += '/?id=' + 3201;
$("#attachments").load(url);
```

However, on load it doesn't do anything. Am i missing something?

I essentially want to call something similar to:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Attachments", "Transactions", new { id = 3301 });}
```

I get the following error on console:

```
http://server:54137/Transactions/@Url.Action(%22Attachments%22,
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? `.load()` - _Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element_ http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Put a `console.log(url);` statement immediately after `var url = ...` and check what it returns.

Comment: your code works fine for me. I used `console.log(url);` and it printed - `/Transactions/Attachments/?id=3201`. So please check the other parts of your code.

Comment: Note also it should be `url += '?id=' + 3201;` (no forward slash)

Comment: Where are you 'doing' the javascript?  What's the filename?  Does it end in .js ?

Answer (score 5):

You must be using an external JavaScript file which will not parse your razor syntax hence the error in your console of `@Url.Action(%22Attachments%22.`.

You have a couple of options:

1. Create a JavaScript function and pass in the url:

   `function loadUrl(url) {
      $("#attachments").load(url);
   }`

Then in your razor call it within a script tag:

```
loadUrl(@Url.Action("Attachments", "Transactions", new { id = @Model.Id })
```

2. Add the url to the html element as data and read it from your JavaScript with the `data` method.

In your razor markup add this:

```
<button data-url="@Url.Action("Attachments", "Transactions", new { id = @Model.Id })" />
```

From your JavaScript event handler read it with:

```
var url = $(this).data('url');
$("#attachments").load(url);
```

I prefer the second option.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't seem to worK? I get the same error when I try option two. I have attached a data value to the option select list and was able to get the url out properly. Then when I try to load it, it still gives me the  error of:

Comment: GET http://localhost:49793/Transactions/@Url.Action(%22Attachments%22 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @SamIAm Hi, you need to make sure that you are calling `@Url.Action` from within the razor file i.e. `.cshtml` or it will not resolve. If you are calling it from an external `.js` file it will just treat it as javascript and resolve as `@Url.Action` rather than a path to the action i.e. `/transactions/attachments`.

Comment: @hutchonoid How can we use this inside a .js file ?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, yes you can. You have a couple of options, create a function with the url as the parameter and pass it in via i.e. `loadThisUrls(@Url.Action....)` to resolve the path or just bundle it up as is and resolve the url as shown above without passing it in.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use [Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) check below

```
var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Attachments", "Transactions"))";
url += '/?id=' + 3201;
$("#attachments").load(url);
```

Comment: You do not need to use `Html.Raw()` - `'@Url.Action("Attachments", "Transactions")';` will return `"/Transactions/Attachments"`